# error in angular.mock.inject when testing service

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, inject

I want to make a test of a service in AngularJS but there is always a problem with the injector.

Here is the service:

```
var projectApp = angular.module("projectApp", []);

projectApp.service("workTimeService", function(){

    this.workHours = function(workHours){
        return workHours;
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
describe("Unit: Testing services", function(){
    var workTimeService;

    beforeEach(function(){
        module("projectApp");
    });
    beforeEach(inject(function(_workTimeService_){
        workTimeService = _workTimeService_;
    }));

    it('Should have funtion', function(){
        expect(angular.isFunction(workTimeService.workHours)).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

I have made it just as in the tutorials but jasmine says that workTimeService is undefined.

Comment: That works good: http://plnkr.co/edit/qgQOObOXTwFlFNoEvoIP?p=preview

Comment: But it still fails in my project, could it be that i need some library or something?

Comment: Be sure your test runner loads angular, angular-mocks, the app code and the app tests, all in that order.